# limit search by selected area in dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

I tried to recover the dropdownlist value and customize the search just for the selected field .. the client will just search in the selected zone in the dropdown .. I tried to find a solution but I could not .. thanks for your help

[image]

this my controller:

```
public JsonResult GetSearchValue(string search,int? gvt)
{

    allsearch = db.Villes.Where(x => x.IdGouvernorat.CompareTo(gvt) == x.gouvernoratModels.IdGouvernorat.CompareTo(gvt)).Where(x => x.VilleName.Contains(search)).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new VilleModels { IdVille = x.IdVille, VilleName = x.VilleName }).ToList();

    return new JsonResult { Data = allsearch, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

this is my cshtml :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.VilleId1, Model.Gouvernorat, "Gouvernorat", new { @class = "btn btn-warning btn-block btn-lg dropdown-toggle",data_toggle="dropdown", @id = "dropdownlist", style = "width:100% !important" })   <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback" style="width:100%">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchInput" placeholder="Entrez votre ville ou code postal" style="width:100%;max-width:100%;height: 45px;">
                    <i id="Icon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" style="color:#7dc24b;padding-top:5px"></i>
                </div>
```

my script :

```
  <script>
    $("#searchInput").autocomplete(
        { 
            search: function () {
                $(this).addClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');
                $('#Icon').removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback');},
            open: function () {
                $(this).removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');
                $('#Icon').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback');},

            source: function (request, response) {


            $.ajax({

                url: '@Url.Action("GetSearchValue", "Home")',
                datatype: "json",
                data: { 

                    gvt: document.getElementById('dropdownlist').selectedIndex(),
                    search: $("#searchInput").val()
                },
                success: function (data) {

                    if (data.length>0) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {


                             $(document).ready(function () {

                                $("#error").slideUp();

                        });
                            return { label: item.VilleName, value: item.VilleName };
                        }
                        )
                        );
                    }                      
                    if (data.length === 0) {

                        $(document).ready(function () {

                                $("#error").show();

                        });
                    }
                },

                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert("error");
                }

            });

        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Do you know how to use the javascript debugger?  pressing f12 in your browser should bring up dev tools, and one of the tabs should have a debugger in it.  With that, you can see if your events are getting hit, if you're selecting the correct value with your autocomplete.

Comment: It'll also have a network tab that will let you know what you're sending to, and getting from the server.

Comment: thanks @sam I am trying to look for error  but without result..

Comment: TypeError: document.getElementById(...).selectedIndex is not a function

Comment: If It's not a function, then what is it?  Your debugger should be able to tell you.

Comment: i w'll change to "  gvt: document.getElementById('dropdownlist')," i have this error now "TypeError: 'click' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLElement."

Comment: may be the problem is into the code from Controller

Comment: You have no element with an `id` attribute of `"dropodownlist"` you want to use [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) instead, or better yet, use jquery to select it.

Comment: i have now this error "TypeError: 'click' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLElement." i change the code controller in JsonRESULT to "allsearch = db.Villes.Where(x =>x.IdGouvernorat.CompareTo(gvt)==x.gouvernoratModels.IdGouvernorat.CompareTo(gvt)).Where(x=>x.VilleName.Contains(search)).AsEnumerable().ToList();var localities = allsearch.Where(i=>i.IdGouvernorat == gvt).Select(x => new VilleModels { IdVille = x.IdVille, VilleName = x.VilleName }).ToList(); return new JsonResult { Data = localities, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };"

Answer (score 0):

here is the Answer that I found, there are two error, one in the Controller Code and other in the Js Script, 
controller Code :

```
     public JsonResult GetSearchValue(string search,int? gvt)
    {         
        List<VilleModels> allsearch = new List<VilleModels>();        
        allsearch = db.Villes.Where(x => x.VilleName.Contains(search)).AsEnumerable().ToList();
        var localities = allsearch.Where(i=>i.IdGouvernorat == gvt).Select(x => new VilleModels { IdVille = x.IdVille, VilleName = x.VilleName }).ToList();
        return new JsonResult { Data = localities, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

JavaScript Code :

```
 <script>
    $("#searchInput").autocomplete(
        { 
            search: function () {
                $(this).addClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');
                $('#Icon').removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback');},
            open: function () {
                $(this).removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');
                $('#Icon').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback');},

            source: function (request, response) {


            $.ajax({

                url: '@Url.Action("GetSearchValue", "Home")',
                datatype: "json",
                data: { 

                    gvt: document.getElementById("dropdownlist").value,
                    search: $("#searchInput").val()
                },
                success: function (data) {

                    if (data.length>0) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {


                             $(document).ready(function () {

                                $("#error").slideUp();

                        });
                            return { label: item.VilleName, value: item.VilleName };
                        }
                        )
                        );
                    }                      
                    if (data.length === 0) {

                        $(document).ready(function () {

                                $("#error").show();

                        });
                    }
                },

                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert("error");
                }

            });

        }
    });

</script>
```

[image]